# How to show selected option and one which user can select

Tags: usability

Wondering what is a best possible solution for situation like below:

[image: Login / Registration form option]

Is it okay to highlight selected one the way login is right now or should go other way that highlight register to show it is clickable and then registration form will appear. In above case register looks little disabled and not looks like if it is clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Both would work. But always with some amount of confusion

But here is the important thing, **Add a big heading saying "Login" just above the username within the bounds of the form**. This will give a confirmation to the user that this is the "Login" form. And then a scan for the "register" term would end end up with clicking it.

And if you do add a heading in the form, then rather than showing "Login | Register" you could just show "Don't have an account yet?, **REGISTER NOW**"

Answer (score 2):

I drew this before I read Saurabh Kumar Suman's answer, but want to post it anyway now.

[image]

Creds to him. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem till saw the solution that Trello came up with -See pictures.

They just have "log in" and 'Register' in one section divided by two columns and depending on where the mouse is they will highlight or hide the background of the section.

[image]

[image]

I hope it helps,
Cheers.